# What are the main applications of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma?

Tags: probability

I'm studying probability theory right now, and I don't get where the Borel-Cantelli lemma leads to apart from the fact that is gives a Borel-Cantelli 0-1 law.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly it is used to prove almost sure convergence of sequences of random variables. What is done is you consider events of the form $A_n=\{\omega:|X_n -X| > \epsilon\}$, show that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(A_n) <\infty$$ and if true for all $\epsilon > 0$, you have

$$X_n \to X \quad a.s$$

I'll update this when I find more applications. For now, the above is key.